# Set Priority of React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

If there are two routes, It renders `List` consistently even if access to `/login`.

```
<Route path="/:mid" component={List} />
<Route path="/login component={Login} />
```

How can I access to `/login` properly?

Comment: What happens if you change the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you change the order and handling `/login` first then only other cases will go the `/:mid` one. Once you access `/login` from the browser it will find the first set `<Route />`.

Try the following:

```
<Route path="/login component={Login} />
<Route path="/:mid" component={List} />
```

I hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Great, Simple, And Intuitive Thanks Need 5 mintues to choice because of stackoverflow system

Answer (score 0):

add `exact` keyword before both. If you add `exact` the order of your routes doesn't matter.

```
<Route exact path="/:mid" component={List} />
<Route exact path="/login component={Login} />
```

Comment: I am sorry I just noticed that your upper route is `/:mid` so when you access `/login` is satisfies the condition `/:mid` here. So you must take your login route on top.